# MS-settings command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I found a list with all Windows command.
Commands like: ms-settings:batterysaver-settings.
I can open these commands in cmd when i place "start" in front of them. 
Commands Like: start ms-settings:batterysaver-settings.
But i want to change the value of battery and not to open it is that possible to do?

Comment: Old thread I know, but still valid. Searched for a way to do this myself, but it looks like an ms-settings value can only be changed by altering a registry value. I have a few shortcuts to reg files which I use to change these values.

Comment: Have you looked at `powercfg /?`.

Comment: `change the value of battery`? Recharge by command instead of using a power adapter? I really wish that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe send parameters to a batch file. Here's an example, slightly elaborate to give you ideas for expansion. Example usage might be `OpenWindowsSettings.bat printers`.

```
@echo off
rem Open one of the Windows Settings pages
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Count arguments and place them in an array
set argCount=0
for %%x in (%*) do (
   set /a argCount += 1
   set "argVec[!argCount!]=%%~x"
)

rem Any parameters and can we act on them?
set argProcessed=0
if %argCount% GTR 0 (
    rem One or more arguments were supplied...use the first one only
    if !argVec[1]! EQU printers (call :ShowPrinters)
    if !argVec[1]! EQU batterysaver-settings (call :ShowBatterySaverSettings)

    if !argProcessed!==0 (echo No parameters recognised...try sending "printers")
) else (
    echo No parameters passed...try sending "printers"
)

rem All done, bye!
goto :EOF

:ShowPrinters
rem Show Windows Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners
set /a argProcessed += 1
start ms-settings:printers
exit /b 0

:ShowBatterySaverSettings
rem Show Windows Settings > System > Battery
set /a argProcessed += 1
start ms-settings:batterysaver-settings
exit /b 0
```

You can find a long list of options for `ms-settings` [here](https://winaero.com/ms-settings-commands-in-windows-10/).